# Use chrome or firefox cookie jar in osx application

Tags: macos, cocoa, google-chrome, cookies

I have written an os x app, but I have a problem.
My program logins on the site each time it downloads a file. It use safari cookie jar, when logins, so safari is logined on this site after my program downloads a file. 
Code I use for login is:

```
NSURL *loginUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.rutracker.org/forum/login.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:loginUrl];
NSURLResponse *loginResponse;
NSError* loginError;
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"login_username=%@&login_password=%@&login=Вход", LoadPlist._username, LoadPlist._password];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[loginRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[loginRequest setTimeoutInterval:15];
[loginRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
[loginRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[loginRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:loginRequest returningResponse:&loginResponse error:&loginError];
```

The problem is that this site allows only one cookie at one time. So if I login in Firefox and then in Safari, in Firefox I get logged out.

So my users, who use Chrome or Firefox as default browser, reported me that they are got logged out from this site because of my program.

So the question is "Can I use Firefox or Chrome cookie jars in my program instead of Safari one?"

Looking forward for your reply.

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can set a custom cookie jar for your request and read cookies from ff/chrome application support folder. You need to know how these browsers store cookies and read them in your code.